# Preciso ler um arquivo .csv e reescrever em outro arquivo .csv sem stopwords usando Python

Tags: python, csv, nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from string import punctuation
import csv


 texto = open('arquivo_sujo.csv','r').read()

 with open('arquivo_limpo.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    palavras = word_tokenize(texto.lower())

    stopwords = set(stopwords.words('portuguese') + list(punctuation))
    palavras_sem_stopwords = [palavra for palavra in palavras if palavra not in stopwords]


    escrita = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    escrita.writerows(palavras_sem_stopwords)
```

Com a correção de writerow para writerows resolveu o problema.
Mas como faço para o novo arquivo ficar com com mesmo formato?
Cada linha está com uma palavra em vez da frase completa.

Comment: Já tentou mudar `writerow` para `writerows`?

Comment: Resolveu,obrigada!Mas estou com outro problema agora.

Comment: O arquivo antigo tem a seguinte frase na primeira linha:                               Desenvolver e trabalhar.                                                                                         
O novo arquivo fica assim:                                                                                Desenvolver                                                                                                          linhavazia                                                                                                                                         trabalhar

Comment: E você quer como?

Comment: Cada linha com uma frase

Comment: Mas a função `word_tokenize` não retorna uma lista de palavras, independente de ser uma frase ou não?

Comment: Sim,é vrd. Será que tem como colocar um delimitador para ele entender o final de cada frase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema principal seja que você está lendo e analisando o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo, sendo que você quer frase por frase. Então, para resolver, você deverá ler cada linha do arquivo de entrada separadamente:

```
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('portuguese') + list(punctuation))

with open('arquivo_sujo.csv') as stream_input, open('arquivo_limpo.csv', 'w') as stream_output:
    for phrase in stream_input:
        words = word_tokenize(phrase.lower())
        without_stopwords = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords]
        stream_output.write(' '.join(without_stopwords) + '\n')
```

Neste caso, cada linha do arquivo de entrada será processada separadamente e gravada no arquivo de saída sem as *stopwords*. Como a formatação de escrita é simples, não vejo necessidade de utilizar o módulo `csv`, o `join` já resolve bem o problema.

Comment: Ainda não tinha me atentado ao join,super resolveu aq,obrigada!